# ReportNG is always showing the first suite in report but executing in last, when I am executing multiple test suites

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, reportng

I am trying to run multiple test suits. For that I am using "suite-files". But the problem is when I am executing this code It is executing the current xml file suite which is named "process" in last, But in report it is showing on the top.

**My testng.xml file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="Process" verbose="1" preserve-order="true" >
```

These are listeners I have used to generate report

```
    <listeners>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
    </listeners> 
    <suite-files>
     <suite-file path="testnglocation.xml" /> 
     <suite-file path="testngdepartment.xml" />
    </suite-files>
  <test name="Process" >

    <classes>
      <class name="AdministrationTestCases.CreateProcess_TC"></class>
      <class name="AdministrationTestCases.UpdateProcess_TC"></class>
      <class name="AdministrationTestCases.DeleteProcess_TC"></class>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

**My Testng Report is here:**

[image: Report]

Comment: are you using Process in same xml file which contains path to other suite xml files and executing?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same xml file.

Comment: @murali: Actually I tried  with different xml file where I used all the three test suites path including Process. called "All suites" which contains(Location, Department and Process suites path). But the issue was for " All suite" the report was showing 0 test case run 0 test failed and 0 passed. thats why I used 3rd xml in which I include 2 suites path  and one is the same test suite.

Comment: @Cedric Beust Can you please help me on this issue.